# Google Cloud Text to Speech INVALID API KEY

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, api-key

I followed this page:

https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-protocol

I generated an access token with:

```
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

and upon entering this:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(my_token_is_in_here) \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
  --data "{
    'input':{
      'text':'Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google,
         based on the Linux kernel and designed primarily for
         touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets.'
    },
    'voice':{
      'languageCode':'en-gb',
      'name':'en-GB-Standard-A',
      'ssmlGender':'FEMALE'
    },
    'audioConfig':{
      'audioEncoding':'MP3'
    }
  }" "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize" > synthesize-text.txt
```

I got this:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   605    0   297  100   308    297    308  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01  3517
```

Buth then I opened up synthesize-text.txt and found

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Clearly gcloud is giving me a token, why doesnt text-to-speech recognize it?

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED]

1) I went to APIs and Services in the 'hamburger' drop down

2) I went to 'credentials' submenu in left column

3) I did 'create credentials' and selected API key
then in my request I formulated as

Curl -H "X-Goog-Api-Key: my-newly-created-API-key" -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" --data "{'input':{'text':'Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google, based on the Linux kernel and designed primarily for touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets.'},'voice':{'languageCode':'en-gb','name':'en-GB-Standard-A','ssmlGender':'FEMALE'},'audioConfig':{'audioEncoding':'MP3'}}" "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize" > synthesize-text.txt

now it works.

So it seems the use of 'Authorization Bearer' with the service account key does not work.
I am using Windows 10.

Comment: isn't the quotation mark placed incorrectly here, I would put it at the end: -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(my_token_is_in_here)

Answer (score 0):

Like Fredrik has said in his comment, there is an error in Google's Docs and it should be: `-H "Authorization: Bearer $(my_token_is_in_here)"` (" at the end, not after `Bearer`)